# dynamically provide file name for encrypting via PGP, in .bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp, pgp

We need to monitor a directory and if any file comes in, we need to encrypt that file using PGP and put it on an FTP server in a specific directory. Can this be acheived via a batch script? If yes, can someone please let me know how. I am new to scripting.

The tool that we were using to acheive all this is suddenly not able to do the PGP via command prompt due to some issues. It used to work from past many years, but suddenly stopped working for executing the PGP command. So we are doing it manually now. We want to automate this process. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your tool can't do it via command line, how are you going to do it in a batch file? A batch file would call your tool via it's command line. You need to provide substantially more information before we can help.

Comment: we are able to do it via command prompt...for some reason we are not able to invoke the pgp command via the tool.....let me know if you need any more details

Comment: I wanted to find out if we can monitor a directory and then if a file comes in, invoke the pgp command and encrypt the file and place the file in a directory...we can monitor that directory via the tool and then FTP the file via the tool..We are only not able to invoke the pgp via the tool....we are able to invoke the same pgp command via the command prompt...any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Provide at least some the code you are using as an example.